# Vim replace multiple empty lines by one empty line

Tags: vim

I was looking for a way to replace multiple empty lines by one empty line and encountered with one solution given below:

```
:g/^$/,/./-j
```

I understand the following:

```
g/   replace each occurrences
^$   start to end is an empty, basically empty line
,    replace empty line by comma
.    maybe repeat last command
-j   minus is go up and j is go down
```

But, I do not understand how period and minus j works in the above code.
Vim is a pretty powerful tool and I hope understanding its syntax help further.

Where can we find the documentation of minus j?

How does period and minus j work here?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
g    Run the command globally, for the entire file
/^$/ Start executing at an empty line…
,    …and continue executing to…
/./  …the first non-empty line (a line that contains
     regexp '.', i.e. any character)
-j   go up and join all selected lines
```

That is, the command [joins](https://vimhelp.org/change.txt.html#%3Aj) all empty lines from an empty line to the line before the next non-empty.